# How do I cross-reference from inside a PSTricks figure?

Tags: cross-referencing, pstricks

I have a pstricks figure that gives an overview of my implementation. From inside the figure I want to cross-reference to the sections that describe the various components in detail.

However, my references do not seem to be resolved. For example the reference to "sec:mysec" in the snippet below is problematic. I translate this example to pdf using the command "pdflatex -shell-escape example.tex" repeatedly.

```
\documentclass[pdf]{article}
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
  \psnode(1,1){A}{Section \ref{sec:mysec}}
\end{pspicture}

\section{My Section}
\label{sec:mysec}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The fact that you're running this under pdfLaTeX could be the problem: Each figure is compiled as a standalone image, which is then converted and included in the document. Since the image is standalone, there is no connection between the original document and the image, leaving the link unresolved.

Comment: that has nothing to do with the workfloaw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}
...
```

or run it with `xelatex` and it will work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
  \psnode(1,1){A}{Section \ref{sec:mysec}}
\end{pspicture}

\section{My Section}
\label{sec:mysec}

\end{document}
```